# Unable to access my Mac keychain due to this

Tags: backup, mac-mini, keychain

i am completely new to Mac.

Recently i tried to change the home folder name of my mac mini. i have gone through a website and followed some instructions to do that. finally i have ended up by creating a completely new user profile with a new home folder name. after some time i have decide to turn back to my old user and deleted the recently created user. This is where all my problems started. Now my deleted user folder is in my hard disk with the the following name - alpha(deleted). This folder is still being treated as my home folder even after logging in from a different user. I am unable to access even my keychain services through mac. Some softwares are asking me to reinstall on this user.... i ran into chaos with this. Can some one help me to make my current user as default and renew my keychain access... Please help me as this is of high priority for me.. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

To change your home directory:

1. Go to System Preferences > Accounts
2. Authenticate
3. Right clic your user and select 'Advanced Options'
4. Type the new path to your home directory or select 'choose' to display a dialog
5. Select 'ok' to save the changes